# Can a virtual Windows 2012 DHCP server be configured to give IP addresses to physical machines?

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, dns, dhcp

I have an internet cafe with A small setup of 5 computers with a generic ISP given router and many customer wireless devices. I need to create a small network. I'm wondering if I installed windows server 2012 with AD DHCP and DNS roles in virtual box and turned of the DHCP on the router, would I be able to configure the virtual server to give IP addresses to the other physical machines?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Should be able to handle the DHCP, depending on your router you may have to point the router to send DHCP requests to the new DHCP server.

If you are going to run the server virtually, It should still work, but it is most likely that the NIC the server is using will need to be dedicated for the server only. I would suggest using Hyper-V for this. I have gotten this setup to work on virtual box before but it proves to be a lot of work to get the NICs to perform right.

I would strongly consider hyper-v for this, you can add it as a feature in windows 10 pro for no cost.

Comment: The router won’t send any DHCP requests at all. It has a static IP after all.

Comment: @DanielB I think Z. Scott meant "forward" DHCP requests to the DHCP server which it absolutely can/will do if configured.  For those interested this is called "DHCP Proxy" and here's how to set it up if you're using Cisco (it's pretty straightforward): http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/7-4/configuration/guides/consolidated/b_cg74_CONSOLIDATED/b_cg74_CONSOLIDATED_chapter_0110.html

Comment: @jkovba Hm, that’s one way to put it. However, it does not apply because you’d totally disable DHCP on the router. DHCP proxying is not something consumer-grade routers do. Instead, you’d put the DHCP server on the same broadcast domain.

Comment: @DanielB  Well, that's exactly what both of the solutions suggest: to disable DHCP on the router.  In fact, this is exactly what needs to happen if DHCP is going to be provided by AD.  If the user has just one subnet, then yes, having all machines on the same subnet as the DHCP server is fine.  If there are multiple subnets, the user will need to enable some form of DHCP proxy (which my Verizon home router supports, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that will work provided the DHCP server is connected to every network that you want to provide dynamic addresses to.

Using VirtualBox, make sure you configure the network cards in "Bridged Mode" so that they appear as normal network cards to the router, as though you were plugging in a physical machine. Configure the DHCP server with a static address, set up your lease pools etc. then disable the DHCP on your router.

I would consider finding that old computer in the loft and installing Linux on it and configure a DHCP server on that. Although I admit this requires a bit more work, it's free and just as powerful.

Does this new network need to be isolated from the wireless customers? You could consider an all-in-one open-source router/dhcp server such as pfSense or Zentyal, then place that on the network in-between the router and your new network.